# Why PrimaryKey NonClustered Index and Separate Clustered Index on Same PrimaryKey Columns are Designed.?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tables are configured where PrimaryKey has been created as Non Clustered Index and with an Additional Clustered Index of the same Columns as of PrimaryKey Columns.

Index Info Sample of this Pattern:
[image: Index Info Sample of this Pattern]

Is there any specific reason why such design is implemented?
And what is the best way to optimize the indexes using Ola Hallengren Scripts?

Comment: Yes, there are several reasons, primarily related to minimising IO and memory usage. What is your specific question?

Comment: @Stu I can't see any reason you would have the exact same columns in both clustered and non-clustered indexes (unless it was a very wide table and you missed off the `INCLUDE` columns)

Answer (score 0):

Non-clustered index is nothing but a smaller table with smaller IO footprint. As you don't have included columns in the non-clustered index, it is just a smaller table, just having OrderID values. Ideally, it is not required.

But, say, Somebody is querying just OrderId, then the non-clustered index will be used, as there is less IO footprint here.

```sql
SELECT OrderiD from Orders
```

But, if somebody is querying other columns in the table, then clustered index will be used.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Orders
```

But, It all depends on the use cases. But, generally, I would suggest to keep smaller number of indexes for easier maintenance.

For example, in the above scenario, whenever a new OrderID is coming, it has to be inserted twice:

1. In the actual data pages, organized by clustered index key
2. In the non-clustered index page